# CSS - Center Footer Content

Tags: html, css

I need to center my footers content and I can not make it works.

I am centering my page using: `#wrap {width: 960px;margin: 0 auto;}`

I have used `float:left;` `float:right;` in my header and content.

So, I try to center my footers content making use of:

`#footer {height:0 auto;min-width:960px;float:left;}`

```
div.inner_footer {height:720px;width:960px;margin:0 auto;}
```

The whole footer goes to the left and shows only half footer in the main page.

Then, I take off
 `float:left;` from `#footer {height:0 auto;min-width:960px;float:left;}` the footer goes straight to the top.

Thank you.

Comment: @meagar - Why the comma? @Martin - could you include some HTML or a link to an example of what you're working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `clear: both` to your footer, and removing `float: left`